# Polynomial Congruences with nonsingular distinct roots.

Tags: number-theory

**Problem:** Suppose that $f(x) \equiv 0 \mod p $ has $n$ distinct nonsingular roots. Show that the same is true of $f(x) \equiv 0 \mod p^k$ for $k \geq 1$. Then show if $p$ is prime and $d$ divides ($p-1$) then $x^d-1=0$ has exactly $d$ roots in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$. Note: $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_p$.

**My approach:** I'm struggling but so far I have that $d$ divides ($p-1$) since there are $d$ distinct nonsingular roots. So, $x^d-1$ divides $x^{p-1} -1$. Moreover, gcd$(x^d-1,x^{p-1}-1) = x^{d}-1$, so $x^{p-1} \equiv 0 \mod p$. This is as far as I got, and I'm not sure if this is the correct approach. Any suggestions?

Comment: should i assume that $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$[x]?

Comment: $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: In this context using $\mathbb{Z}_p$ might confuse with the ring of p-adic integers.

Do you define nonsingular root as one with multiplicity 1?

Comment: You can use Hensel lifting to lift simple roots of $f \pmod p$ to simple roots of $f \pmod {p^k}$ for any $k$. But not sure how to show that simple roots of $f \pmod {p^k}$ necessarily correspond to simple roots of $f \pmod p$.